# Find the equation of the radius

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Find the equation of the radius of the circle $x^2-4x-6y+y^2=23$ and passing through the point $(4,5)$.

My attempt:
Here the equation of the circle is:
$$x^2-4x-6y+y^2=23$$
$$(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=6^2$$
hence,
center$$(h,k)=(2,3)$$
and radius$$r=6units$$.
Now, what should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

center is (2,3) The radius passes through (4,5) . So, the Equation is the line passing through (2,3) and (4,5).